# Adding own certificate authority to macOS

Tags: macos, command-line, certificate, git, ssl

I currently facing the problem that I created a certificate authority certificate and would like to add this custom CA to macOS.
The general way would be to add it to the "System" area in my key chain and trust the certificate. This works fine for e.g. browsers.

Now I would like to use command line tools like git and curl or one of intellij's IDEs. But then I am running into the following error message:

```
SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

I found out that `curl` on macOS is using LibreSSL. So my assumption would be that LibreSSL is not looking into macOS keychain. Do I think in the right direction?

Or do I need to add my CA certificate to an additional directory?

Comment: Are intellij's IDEs written in Java? If so, you might need to add the Certificate Authority for the Java runtime. See [Add root CA certificates to trust stores on MacOS](https://learnings.bolmaster2.com/posts/add-certificates-to-trust-stores.html#java)

Comment: See also [Where's the ca cert bundle on OSX?](https://superuser.com/questions/247686/wheres-the-ca-cert-bundle-on-osx), which discusses curl on macOS.

Comment: Thanks for the links! They solved my problem. I found out that I have an cert.pem (like described in Where's the ca cert bundle on OSX?) under /etc/ssl/cert.pem. I simply added my CA certificate and after that all mentioned tools are working!